# Folders on File Explorer -> Desktop do not match actual desktop: Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, desktop

Here is my Desktop as shown through the File Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer]

Here is my Desktop as viewed with no file explorer:

[image: Plain Desktop]

I want the Desktop link of the File Explorer to match what is actually on my desktop - so I want it to not display "Libraries", "Computer", "Network", etc.

I have already tried *Right Click Desktop* > *Personalize* > *Change Desktop Icons* and uncheck these Desktop Icons...but this only removes from the "physical desktop" while leaving them still in the File Explorer.

Comment: Check C:\Users\your user name\Desktop. This will show your exact desktop icons.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the Desktop virtual folder, not the actual directory location so it is going to contain other things. Like vembutech suggested if you look in C:\users\"username"\Desktop you will find the actual directory location which will show a more accurate representation of what is on the desktop.

Quote from wiki about Special folders:
The "Desktop" virtual folder is not the same thing as the "Desktop" special folder. The Desktop virtual folder is the root of the Windows Shell namespace, which contains other virtual folders

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder#cite_ref-TheShellNamespace_5-0